# seaborn displot IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: indexing, seaborn

After a long time, yesterday I started reviewing some old codes using seaborn. However, I started having issues evrytime I use distplot/displot, as I always get error message about some error like this:

```
a=sns.load_dataset('iris')
sns.displot(data=a,x='sepal_length',kind='kde')
```

and I get this message:

****Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in 
sns.displot(data=a,x='sepal_length',kind='kde')
File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py", line 2299, in displot
p.plot_univariate_density(**kde_kws)
File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py", line 1019, in plot_univariate_density
artist, = ax.plot(support, density, **artist_kws)
File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 1666, in plot
lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 225, in **call**
yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 399, in _plot_args
ncx, ncy = x.shape[1], y.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range****

I recently updated seaborn to last version (0.11.2) but I don't know if it's related to this attitude. Consider that if I repeat the example above without adding kind= 'kde' or other inputs, it works. Unfortunately this was a code used to work before. Do u think I have to delete last version in favour of an older one?

Comment: Which matplotlib version are you using? (The error occurs somewhere in matplotlib.)

Comment: My Matplotlib version is 3.1.1

Comment: Probably it'll help to upgrade.  Maybe it's also needed to upgrade pandas.

Comment: Updated Matplotlib at 3.5.2. It seems ok now. Tomorrow I'll check it better. Thanks